# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.routeName') - React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a problem with React Navigation's Drawer Navigator. I have a screen where the user verify the email. And if it is verified, it will navigate to HomeScreen which is inside a Drawer Navigation

Here's my code :

```
navigateToHomeScreen () {
  const actions = NavigationActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    actions: [
      NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: 'NavigationDrawer'})
    ]
  })

  this.props.navigation.dispatch(actions)
  this.props.dismissModal()
}
```

function inside `verification.js`

```
const NavigationDrawer = DrawerNavigator({
  HomeScreen: {
   screen: HomeScreen,
   navigationOptions: {
     drawerLabel: 'Home'
  }
 }
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'HomeScreen',
  contentComponent: props => <DrawerContent {...props} />
})

export default NavigationDrawer
```

`NavigationDrawer.js`

```
const PrimaryNav = StackNavigator(
{
  RegisterScreen: {screen: RegisterScreen},
  ConfirmVerificationCodeScreen: {screen:ConfirmVerificationCodeScreen},
  LoginScreen: {screen: LoginScreen},
  NavigationDrawer: {screen: NavigationDrawer},
  HomeScreen: {screen: HomeScreen}
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'LoginScreen',
  headerMode: 'none'
})

export default PrimaryNav
```

`AppNavigation.js`

And when I navigate to home screen inside verification.js, it thrown an error

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.routeName')`

Please help. I have double checked the boilerplate and it is totally fine. I have imported everything that the files need

Comment: You can check this https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3148

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to solve by adding this,

```
drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle'

to the drawer, configs fixed the issue for me.
```

Look here: https://github.com/react-community/react-
navigation/issues/3148#issuecomment-352778884

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug of react-navigation. 
Since it's fixed now, you can resolve it by updating your react-navigation.

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3148

check this link.